# My Mojang account has disappeared; can I still play Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I had Minecraft bought for me a long, long time ago (like, back when you had to actually open up the .JAR file and put the mods in there) by someone who I am no longer in contact with. I got bored of it and didn't play it any until a few months ago.

I migrated my old Minecraft account to a new Mojang account and successfully played the game for a month or so, but then the launcher started asking me to log in again, and this time wouldn't accept my credentials.

It kinda seems like half of Mojang's systems just won't accept my password, and half of them don't know about my account at all. Trying the "migrate account" form says "this account has already been migrated," but trying to log in says "password/username incorrect." Trying to reset my password just gives a confirmation message and no E-Mail ever comes.

I tried contacting Mojang support about this but they asked for bank records and a receipt, neither of which I have (the receipt is in my old E-Mail account, which was hacked into by the person I mentioned.)

There's still a file called `usercache.json` in the game install directory; there's what looks like a session ID or something in there. I remember reading something about putting a session key into the Minecraft JAR on the command line. It's got an expiration date on it that's passed, though.

Anyway, is there any way I can play Minecraft without having to shell out 30 bucks for something I already own?

EDIT:

To clarify, trying to log in to Minecraft or Mojang with the new credentials doesn't work any more than the old ones.

Comment: A friend of mine actually has the very same problem. He wanted to play after a long time again, migrated his account, and now seems unable to login. Passwort reset shows confirmation, but no eMail ever arrives. In case you solve this problem, please make sure to make it an answer here and mark it as answer to let me and others know.

Comment: Without access to the email address recovery of the account won't be possible

Comment: @Ramhound I have the EMail address the account is under, just not the EMail address it was bought under.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the Mojang account's email address as your username instead of your original username.

The reason it may have still been working after migration is proberbly because your existing account credentials/session data.

Comment: Don't forget to use the Mojang password!!

Comment: Tried that. Doesn't work. I can't log in to Mojang's website with the Mojang credentials any more than I can get a password reset from them.